# Get folder name on selection of folder from input field

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have used below code to select a folder and parse all the files within folder .I will get a list of all files but how can I get a folder name alone

Suppose folder path is C:/Foldername I am getting all files within this path I want to get the name of the folder also **Foldername** how can I acheive this using nodejs?

HTML

```
<input id="customFile" type="file"  name="fileList" webkitdirectory multiple />
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("customFile").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        console.log(files[i].webkitRelativePath)
    };
});
```

Comment: Do you have the path?

Comment: yes I am getting all files within folder in  console.log(files[i].webkitRelativePath)

Comment: Couldn't you get the Foldername from your path

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
document.getElementById("customFile").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
            let files = event.target.files;
            for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                console.log(files[i].webkitRelativePath);
                // just an idea how to get the path name from the full path
                var fileName = files[i].webkitRelativePath.substring(0,files[i].webkitRelativePath.indexOf('/'));
                console.log(fileName);
            };
        });
```

The idea here, is to extract the name of the parent folder form the full path. you should extract it from your loop ofc (this is just an example) like this:

```
if (files.length>0) {
    var fileName = files[0].webkitRelativePath.substring(0,files[0].webkitRelativePath.indexOf('/'));
    console.log(fileName);
}
```

The condition is used to make sure that the folder is not empty.

Good luck!