# HTML multi-file input to get directory (Electon app)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML input field:

```html
<input
  name="folderInput"
  type="file"
  id="folderInput"
  webkitdirectory
  directory
  multiple
  onchange="selectFolder();"
/>
```

It's a *folder input*, where you can select a folder and the code can get the files.

But when I get the files on a function, it returns me the full path of every file.

Actual behavior (example)
If the user introduced:

- folder called `foo` which contains a file `text.txt`
- and a folder called `bar` which contains a file `fooboar.txt`

the code returns me this:

```
(fullpath)/foo/text.txt
(fullpath)/bar/foobar.txt
```

How could I get the `(fullpath)`?

How can I get the **path of the folder** that the user has chosen?

Comment: Why do you care where the user stores the files on their machine? You've got the files and their relative paths.

Comment: Is this a node.js or other kind of application?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey As a small project, I was trying to do a text editor with electron, where you set a folder and the list of subfolders and files appears (similar to code editors), and you can edit them as .txt files.

Comment: CodeForFun It's and electron application, so I can use nodejs in js files imported from html.

Comment: Well, you're using components geared to browsers on the world wide web. Imagine anyone being able to find out what your internal folder structure is just by asking you to upload a file or a directory!

Comment: Heretic Monkey So, how could I do something similar? Or it's impossible?

Comment: @Brian3647 This __important context belongs in the question__:   `Electron application using NodeJs`, please [edit] to update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highest hierarchy you can get via this input and JavaScript is the **top-most folder-name** within the *relative* path – the one the user has chosen.

In your given example, this is assumed to be `foo` or `bar`.

⚠️ You will not get the absolute path (because this information is hidden, also for privacy/security reasons).

#### How to get path segments

Use string property `webkitRelativePath` and split-of the substring until first occurrence of path-separator `/`.

#### See also

- [Get folder name on selection of folder from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65336425/5730279), already answered question
- MDN reference documentation [`webkitdirectory` input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) with example